# Word count for text in column

Tags: r, tm, word-count

I have a dataset with a column containing text as follows

```
    Column1
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    dapagliflozin 10 MG / metFORMIN hydrochloride 
    dapagliflozin 5 MG / metFORMIN hydrochloride  
    Fortamet       
    Glucophage      
    Glumetza      
    metFORMIN hydrochloride      
    metFORMIN hydrochloride  / pioglitazone 15 MG     
    metFORMIN hydrochloride  / pioglitazone 30 MG
```

I am trying to obtain the word count for every unique word, for example, word count for metFormin, word count for hydrochloride, etc. I need help; I tried table function, but it uses the whole row as one word and that's not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a combination of `strsplit/unlist/table`.  Split the column strings with `strsplit` specifying the `split` as space (`\\s+`).  The output will be a `list`.  Use `unlist` to change the list to vector and then use `table` to get the count.

```
 table(unlist(strsplit(yourdf$Column1, '\\s+'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use a text analysis package designed for this:

```
> require(quanteda)
> dfm(myColumn)
Creating a dfm from a character vector ...
   ... lowercasing
   ... tokenizing
   ... indexing 1 document
   ... shaping tokens into data.table, found 21 total tokens
   ... summing tokens by document
   ... indexing 8 feature types
   ... building sparse matrix
   ... created a 1 x 8 sparse dfm
   ... complete. Elapsed time: 0.047 seconds.
Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 8 features.
1 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
       features
docs    dapagliflozin fortamet glucophage glumetza hydrochloride metformin mg pioglitazone
  text1             2        1          1        1             5         5  4            2
```